# How to execute a rake task using mina?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rake, mina

I want to run a rake task (migrate) contained in my Rakefile in my Sinatra app. I am using Mina to deploy. `rake migrate` works great if I run it on the server or on my development, but I cannot get Mina to execute the task.

My current deploy looks like this within `config/deploy.rb`

```
task :deploy => :environment do
  deploy do
    # Put things that will set up an empty directory into a fully set-up
    # instance of your project.
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'

     to :launch do
      queue "sudo /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload"
    end
  end
end
```

I tried both `queue "rake migrate"` and `queue "#{rake} migrate"` within the deploy block and within the launch block but it always complains `bash: command not found`

Comment: Are you using `rbenv` or `rvm` on your server?

Comment: @mechanicalfish I am using RVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mina uses `ssh` to run remote commands. That means that the commands run in a different environment as when you log in. This is causing problems with `rvm` and `rbenv` as they are not initialised properly. Luckily, `mina` has [`rvm` support](http://nadarei.co/mina/docs/lib/mina/rvm.html), you just have to set it up:

```
require 'mina/rvm'
task :environment do
  invoke :'rvm:use[ruby-1.9.3-p125@gemset_name]'
end

task :deploy => :environment do
  ...
end
```

You can do a similar thing for rbenv ([documentation](http://nadarei.co/mina/docs/lib/mina/rbenv.html))

Answer (score 5):

in Mina, use `ssh` to execute rake not quite a smart move.

`mina 'rake[rake_taks:taks_whatever_you_write]' on= environment`

that is better.